# Initialise Table adapter manually

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How would I go about initialising a table adapter properly pragmatically? Normally, I would use the table adapter that get's created for me when I drag and drop the Data Table onto my form, but have never used one in a custom class before.

Cheers!

EDIT:

I think I need to explain my scenario in more detail.

I've added a method on my datatable inside my dataset. I want to be able to call this method from inside a custom class. Therefore I'd need a valid Table Adapter to be created to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ...", c))
{
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", field1);
    etc...

    sda.Fill(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void FillData()
{
    // 1
    // Open connection
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(
    Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
    {
        c.Open();
        // 2
        // Create new DataAdapter
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))
        {
            // 3
            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);

            // 4
            // Render data onto the screen
            // dataGridView1.DataSource = t; // <-- From your designer
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
Why don't you make this method in a separate class that will be called in your data table and wherever else you will need to? You will just make an instance of the class and call the public method of that class.

Comment: Why don't you make this method in a separate class that will be called in your data table and wherever else you will need to? You will just make an instance of the class and call the public method of that class.